# Error while sending large size files to multicast endpoint in camel

Tags: java, apache-camel

Am facing a scenario where i need to send a large file size to multicast endpoint. My route is as follows.I am trying to send a single file of 100 MB or more than that files from abcd endpoint to xyz and from xyz to efg and test queue. I could able to send the whole 100MB from abcd to xyz but not from xyz to efg and test queue. It is sending only few files and other files are missing in the multicast route.Also am getting 3 types of error in fuseesb log:

```
1. org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException: Cannot store file: D:\xyz\samplebigfiles.txt at org.apache.camel.component.file.FileOperations.storeFile(FileOperations.java:264)[147:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.0.fuse-71-047]

2. Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\abcd\samplebigfiles.txt (The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)[:1.6.0_22]

3. java heap space error


<route>
  <from uri="file:///D:/abcd" />
   <to uri="file:///D:/xyz" />
</route>
<route>
  <from uri="file:///D:/xyz" />
    <multicast>
    <to uri="file://D:/efg" />
    <to uri="jms:queue:test" />
    </multicast>
</route>
```

Please suggest me some solution to resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

When you work with files, you would need to consider the read lock strategy to use, to avoid reading the files, while another process is writing it etc. See more details at the Camel file documentation: http://camel.apache.org/file2

And you should not send a 100MB file over a JMS queue. Messaging is not designed to work with such big payloads. For example Apache ActiveMQ has a FAQ about this at: http://activemq.apache.org/can-i-send-really-large-files-over-activemq.html

And notice Apache Camel does not support the special BlobMessage type ActiveMQ provides. Though this functionality is seldom in use. And its implemented to store the file out of band, and use FTP to transfer the payload.

And speaking of FTP while transferring such big payloads, using FTP / SCP or some other ways is possibly better. Camels has FTP and SCP components:

- http://camel.apache.org/ftp2
- http://camel.apache.org/jsch.html

Comment: Thank you for your response Claus, I tried using readLock=markerFile in my route and checked with 33.6MB file. Still it was raising the same error. Also the lock created in from endpoint appears forever, the to endpoint which is a file endpoint appears(showing 0kB or 34,467KB ) and disappears. And in other hand, no messages are pushed to queue (which is the another endpoint of multicast). Am confused totally with this output.